# Expressing any f(x,y) using only addition and unary functions?

Tags: gn.general-topology, reference-request

Suppose we have a continuous function $f:R^2\rightarrow R$.  I was told of the following remarkable theorem: $f$ can be expressed as the composition of continuous unary functions (that is, functions from $R\rightarrow R$) and addition.

Could anyone give me a reference (or name) for this theorem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is "due in successively more exact forms to Kolmogorov, Arnol'd and a succession of mathematicians ending with Kahane", to quote T.W. Korner on the subject.

I am informed that the proof I met is prepared using:

J.-P. Kahane *Sur le treizieme probleme de Hilbert, le theoreme de superposition de Kolmogorov et les sommes algebriques d'arcs croissants* in the conference proceedings *Harmonic analysis, Iraklion 1978* Springer 1980

G. G. Lorenz, *Approximation of functions* Chelsea Publishing Co. 1986 (First Ed. 1966)

A. G. Vituskin *On the representation of functions by superpositions and related topics* in L'Enseignement Mathématique, 1977, Vol 23, pages 255-320

[This is all from these skeleton notes (no proofs) [here](http://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~twk/CV4.pdf) (Links to pdf; See Chapter 1 and Chapter 11 for references)]

Answer (score 10):

I think this was proven by Kolmogorov. 
See the following reference:
A. N. Kolmogorov, “On the representation of continuous functions of several variables by
superpositions of continuous functions of one variable and addition”, Dokl. Akad. Nauk
SSSR 114 (1957), 953–956; English transl., Amer. Math. Soc. Transl. (2) 28 (1963), 55–59.

Answer (score 0):

I find it interesting that this theorem is used as a theoretical basis for neural networks. I had never heard this before.

Věra Kůrková, *Kolmogorov's theorem and multilayer neural networks* 1992

Comment: There seems to be some debate on the relevance of Kolmogorov's theorem to learning theory.  A rebuttal can be found in "Representation Properties of Networks: Kolmogorov's Theorem is Irrelevant" by Girosi and Poggio, 1989.  A PDF copy is online here:

http://cbcl.mit.edu/projects/cbcl/people/poggio/journals/girosi-poggio-NeuralComputation-1989.pdf




Comment: I was thinking along the same lines. It would guess that the functions postulated by Kolmogorov's theorem would be smooth only in simple cases. Thanks.